# "Install Labview 2020 sp1 community " cannot be opened because apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: install, apple-silicon

I recently upgrade to the newest Macbook pro M1, from a 2018 intel model. I was trying to install this software to my new machine.
and encountered the following:
“LabVIEW 2020 SP1 Community 64-bit” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
This is the newest version that I could find from [here](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/software-products/download.labview.html#369643).  I could only find one thread that treat this [matter](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/LabVIEW-2020-SP1-community-for-Mac/td-p/4137811?profile.language=en) but doesn't really help much in my case. So would greatly appreciate any insight from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps that are not distributed via the AppStore now require Notarization on top of being signed by a paid Apple Developer ID which means the developer must submit their application to Apple for review so that Apple can issue a notarization signature the developer can "staple" apply to the App. Otherwise you will see that warning and the App will not run by default.

To work around the problem: Open the /Applications folder with Finder.  Right-click the LabVIEW application icon and select Open.  A dialog will appear and you can allow the App to open. The App might immediately quit, try opening the App normally and this time it should work.

Send an email to the software vendor and ask them to Notarize their App for the newer macOS versions. At some point in the future, Apple may remove the ability to work around running an App that hasn't been notarized.